# does visual studio express 2013 come with blend, how can i open it?

Tags: c#, wpf, expression-blend, visual-studio-2013

I have been looking a for a while today and i didn't find anything about it, there is a lot about blend for visual studio 2013, but does it come with the express version for desktop, and if it does how can i access to it or download it.
thanks

Answer (score 7):

Blend does NOT come with Visual Studio 2013 Express.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2013 Professional comes with Blend.

Answer (score 2):

The feature matrix looks like Blend is included in Ultimate, Premium and Professional. It looks like Express and Test Professional come without Blend.

http://www.visualstudio.com/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs

Update: Just bought VS pro 2013 and it has Blend. So my assumption was right.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate edition comes with the Blend but not in express or other editions only in ultimate full edition which is approximately 2.81Gbs'

Comment: what about professional and premium, i think they also come with blend

Comment: now i am absolutely shure, any version starting with professional comes with blend (except Test Professional). just bought VS pro 2013, and it has blend :)